# JSTL for each, var contains square brackets

Tags: java, foreach, set, jstl

I have a `HashSet` of Strings, which is made with the following code:

```java
Set<String> scripts = new HashSet<>();
String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
scripts.add(contextPath + "/resources/scripts/jquery.cycle2.js");
scripts.add(contextPath + "/resources/scripts/jquery.cycle2.center.js");
scripts.add(contextPath + "/resources/scripts/slideshow.js");
request.setAttribute("scripts", scripts);
```

Now in a JSP page, with JSTL, I do a normal forEach loop:

```java
<c:if test="${not empty scripts}">
    <c:forEach var="script" items="${scripts}" >
        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="${script}">
                          </script> 
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

When loading the page, this results in:

```html
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="[/InfoKiosk/resources/scripts/jquery.cycle2.center.js">
                          </script> 

<script type="text/javascript"
        src=" /InfoKiosk/resources/scripts/jquery.cycle2.js">
                          </script> 

<script type="text/javascript"
        src=" /InfoKiosk/resources/scripts/slideshow.js]">
                          </script>
```

Notice the **square brackets** (`[` and `]`) that appear before the first script source and after the last. Where do they come from?

Comment: Try using a `List<String>` instead of a `Set`.

Comment: @JasperdeVries we had used List initially, we tried Set in an attempt to solve the problem. The cause was something completely different, as I'll explain in my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occured because the `scripts` variable was set in a JSP through an attribute for a custom tag, like this:

```html
<t:genericpage scripts="${scripts}">
....
```

Of course, this converted the collection to a string by calling its `toString()` method. We have solved it in a different way, by setting the request attribute in the servlet.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason it is calling `toString()` on your set. This then turns your set into `[script1, script2, script3]`, calling `foreach` on this string splits on the comma, creating the effect we see.

I could see exactly what you were seeing when I replace
`request.setAttribute("scripts", scripts);`
with
`request.setAttribute("scripts", scripts.toString());`

I could not reproduce what you were seeing without this, however I was running java 6.

Not an answer, but a helpful insight I hope!

Comment: This is indeed a helpful answer. I would like to know why this is, since it is otherwise perfectly possible to set collections as attributes...