# Why is fn:escapeXml() adding square brackets to String

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I have a Java/JSP webapp that has started showing a bug after I added `fn:escapeXml()` to a tag that constructs a URL.

The original code was

```
    <p id="provide-link">
        Follow this link to see the source data:
        <q:link href="../resources/source-data.jsp" 
                sourceData="${chart.parameters.source}">
            Source Data
        </q:link>
    </p>
```

`q:link` is a custom tag that creates a hyperlink out of `href` as the base and `sourceData` as a GET parameter.  For example, if `chart.parameters.source = 'dataset03'`, then the link embedded in the page is

`../resources/source-data.jsp&sourceData=dataset03`.

The custom tag `q:link` is written to handle cases where `chart.parameters.source` is a Collection of multiple data sources, which is an allowed case.

This code works normally, but is vulnerable to script insertion attacks due to the GET parameter.  Thus, I've added the JSTL function `escapeXml()` to the code to prevent this:

```
    <p id="provide-link">
        Follow this link to see the source data:
        <q:link href="../resources/source-data.jsp" 
                sourceData="${fn:escapeXml(chart.parameters.source)}">
            Source Data
        </q:link>
    </p>
```

When I do this, square brackets get added to the URL:

`../resources/source-data.jsp&sourceData=[dataset03]`

This is a problem because `[dataset03]` is not a valid value for the parameter.

The only thing I've found online about this problem is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934394/jstl-for-each-var-contains-square-brackets), which doesn't provide a full answer but suggests that `${fn:escapeXml(chart.parameters.source)}` might be outputting as an Array now that it includes `fn:escapeXml()`.  The theory is that `q:link` then catches and retains the Array brackets when it converts to String.

Anyone know what's happening and how to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

Your last suggestion seems correct to me, the fn:escapeXml function has an argument of type String. If the parameter passed is a Collection, it will be converted through a toString() method (that add the []). It appends before the fn:escapeXml() call, so it’s not added inside it.

Rem: it doesn’t append without the escapeXml function because your custom tag retrieve and work on the Collection directly (iterating on its values inside probably).

One solution to convert the Collection passed as argument before passing it to the escapeXml fct; through a tag or EL expression (map()...)

Rem2: instead of using a custom tag to encode your url parameters, there are already these standard JSTL tags that do a similar job :
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_param_tag.htm
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm

Hope that will help,
Kind regards,
Cedric